# Что включает в себя схема предложения?

Tags: графика

Что включает в себя схема предложения?
Нужны ли там второстепенные члены предложения?

Answer (score 2):

Смотря какая схема, какой класс.В младших классах указываются, там только простые предложения. В остальных указывается грамматическая основа и осложнение: обособленные члены, вводные, обращения, однородные члены.

[-,/.../, =].[ О и О].

В сложных только грамматические основы, осложняющие элементы.

[- =] и [- = ].

[- = ],(что).